# Convert from Array to ICollection<T>

Tags: c#

What is the ***best*** way to convert from `T[]` to `ICollection<T>` in C#?

Comment: There is no conversion, an array of T implements ICollection<T>.

Comment: Arrays do not implement `ICollection<T>` safely - see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12100850/562906).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Arrays of `T` are assignable to `ICollection` of `T`, as an array of `T` implements `IList` of `T`. `IList` of `T` itself extends `ICollection` of `T`, so you can simply assign an array to an `ICollection`.

```
class Foo {}

Foo [] foos = new Foo [12];
ICollection<Foo> foo_collection = foos;
```

Comment: Are you saying that, basically, there is no need to *convert* because Array already *is* an ICollection?

Comment: you can't convert array Foo[] to ICollection

Answer (score 29):

**Short answer**:

Use [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx). Don't rely on `T[]` being assignable to `ICollection<T>` unless you are aware of the following and know what you're doing.

If you need it read-only, it's better to use [`Array.AsReadOnly(T[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_AsReadOnly__1___0___) and avoid the extra copy, and also avoid the problems detailed below.

---

**Detailed answer:**

Although array of T (ie. `T[]`) *technically* implements `IList<T>` (and `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`), it **does not actually implement** the entire `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` interfaces, as mentioned [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czz5hkty%28v=vs.100%29):

> ...The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`.

In other words, if you just cast the array to `ICollection<T>` you will get `NotSupportedException` as soon as you call any of the aforementioned methods.

So the best way to convert an array **safely** to an `ICollection<T>` would be to create a new object, such as using `Linq`'s `ToList()`:

```
T[] array;

// Will create a new list based on the current contents of the array
ICollection<T> collection = array.ToList();
```

Comment: This is the far better answer, accepted doesn't really mention the "danger" of casting to these without care.

Comment: So If I know I'm not going to modify the collection at all, it is is safe to cast ICollection<T>?

Comment: @DanielLorenz if you want it as read only, it's better to enforce it with [`Array.AsReadOnly(T[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_AsReadOnly__1___0___)

Comment: I didnt want the overhead of creating something new since there is overhead when you start getting lots of items on an array. @sinelaw

Comment: @DanielLorenz I don't think AsReadOnly has a big overhead, it just wraps the existing array (according to the docs I linked to)

Comment: @sinelaw hmm.. this calls for experimentation!

Comment: *"it **does not actually implement** the entire `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` interfaces"* -- Technically it does. It's not even an option, since implementing an interface partially is an unknown concept in C#. Maybe you wanted to say *"support"* instead of *"implement"*.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer and the comment, if you want to go the *other* way, you use the `ToArray()` method on `IEnumerable<T>` (which `ICollection<T>` descends from).